# How to recover an overflowed long in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Using PowerBuilder 12.5...

My client stored a value in a long and saved it to the database. Eventually the values exceeded the amount possible in a long so it started storing negatives in the database. I know how to recover the original number if it is an integer that overflowed:

```
ABS(ai_int) + ((32768 - abs(ai_int)) * 2)
```

but using the same formula with the size of a `long` in 32768 does not work. Can someone help me get the negative number back to what the user wanted?

Comment: Where was it overflowed: in the PB client, or in the DBMS? If the latter, which DBMS?

Answer (score 2):

Simply assign the Long to an UnsignedLong and it will be the expected value. For a demo create a window and put a MultilineEdit on it then put this in the Open event:

```
long ll_max = 2147483647
long ll_a, ll_b, ll_c
unsignedlong lul_a, lul_b, lul_c
string ls_out

ll_a = ll_max + 1
ll_b = ll_a + 1
ll_c = ll_b + 1
lul_a = ll_a
lul_b = ll_b
lul_c = ll_c

ls_out = string(ll_max) + "~r~n"
ls_out += string(ll_a) + "~r~n"
ls_out += string(ll_b) + "~r~n"
ls_out += string(ll_c) + "~r~n~r~n"
ls_out += string(ll_max) + "~r~n"
ls_out += string(lul_a) + "~r~n"
ls_out += string(lul_b) + "~r~n"
ls_out += string(lul_c) + "~r~n"

mle_1.text = ls_out
```

The above produces this output:

```
2147483647
-2147483648
-2147483647
-2147483646

2147483647
2147483648
2147483649
2147483650
```

Comment: Good idea! Unless the overflow has been more than one bit, but then again, unless you assume only one bit of overflow, any recovery will be impossible. Still, very cool idea!

Comment: Even in that case you may be able to use other information to order or partition the rows enough to find the places the value rolled over. You could even use backups to determine which rows were in the table as of each backup date.

Comment: I'm guessing you're assuming these are overflows from incrementing (+1); I'm including the possibility that one day someone decided to add 4 billion to an integer. Unless serious audit tracking was done (e.g. tracking components of every operaton), I don't think there's any recovering from that one.

Comment: I'm certainly assuming that each change is at least a few orders of magnitude below the maximum size of an integer. It it's not there are much more serious problems with the system than running out of space in an integer. There's also the possibilty that the values aren't sequential at all. One could imagine a PB app connected to a Frob Detector that counts and logs Frobs over some interval. If Frobs are random and the counter overflows, there's no way to infer the lost data.